# RestKit object mapping POST response, "CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class mapping operation"

Tags: ios, post, http-post, restkit, restkit-0.20

The response object for a POST request crashes while trying to map to an object. The following output is printed “CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class mapping operation”

As the message suggests a RKObjectRequestOperation is being used rather than a RKManagedObjectRequestOperation. My problem may be complicated since the outer object is a normal nsobject but within it there's a member variable that contains an nsmanagedObject entity. I’ve been spelunking through the code and I’m not sure how to steer the code into the direction I want. What’s even more galling is that I’m able to map to the response object for a GET request. The response object is essentially the same with the exception. Here’s the code I’m using

My response object is a normal NSObject with a nested managed object within it.

```
// response definition
@interface PDResponse : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *message;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *success;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id value;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *exception;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *transactionId;
@end

// Mapping for the download object
RKEntityMapping * repMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"PDRepresentative" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
repMapping = @[@"repId"];
[repMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"RepId": @"repId",
                                               @"First": @"firstName",
                                               @"Middle": @"middleName",
                                               @"Last": @"lastName",
                                               @"Address1": @"address1",
                                               @"Address2": @"address2",
                                               @"City": @"city",
                                               @"Zip": @"zip",
                                               @"Country": @"country",
                                               @"Company": @"company",
                                               @"Phone": @"phone",
                                               @"PhonePersonal": @"phonePersonal",
                                               @"Fax": @"fax",
                                               @"Email": @"email",
                                               @"EventId": @"event.eventId",
                                               @"Specialty": @"specialty"}];

RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PDResponse class]];
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"Message": @"message",
                                                      @"Success": @"success",
                                                      @"Ex": @"exception",
                                                      @"TransactionId": @"transactionId"}];

[responseMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Value"
                                                                                toKeyPath:@"value"
                                                                              withMapping:repMapping]];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping: responseMapping
                                                                                  method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                             pathPattern:@"PostAddOrUpdateRep/"
                                                                                 keyPath:nil
                                                                             statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];



// POST Object
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [objectManager requestWithObject:self method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"PostAddOrUpdateRep/" parameters:nil];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                               success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
                                                                                   PDResponse *response = mappingResult.firstObject;
                                                                                   response = [response isKindOfClass:[PDResponse class]] ? response : nil;
                                                                                   TRACE_LOG(@"%@", response);

                            }
                                                                               failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                                                                                   ERROR_LOG(@"Failure int %s %@, %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, operation, error);

                                                                               }];
[objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
self.sent = @(YES);
```

I've observed many other posts and have done the following in accordance to the info I found from those posts.

It was suggested in another post to remove and add slashes due to problems with descriptors not being able to map to paths properly but that wasn’t the case. I opted to not use the postObject:path:parameters:success:failure function since it was giving me an error for mapping the response where the target object variable was assigned to of type PDRepresentative rather than of PDResponse.

I'm also able to properly upload, so my managedObjectStore is fine. As you can see I'm using a RKEntityMapping object so, one would hope that this would tell the code to use a NSManagedObject rather than NSObject.

A user named, Wain, suggested in another post that mixing managed and non managed items could pose a potential problem. I'm inclined to believe him but I wanted to through this out there since I did get it to work for my response from my GET request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was being foolish and simply changed the function that created the request operation to `managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:managedObjectContext:success:fail` rather than using `objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:fail`. I simply read what I wrote in the first paragraph of my question.

God I'm a moron.